# php cURL - Slow upload limit - how to optimize?

Tags: php, curl

I am using cURL to transfer data between my website and a partner's website.

The request is very long (~ 18 seconds), yet the amount of information is quite small (~ 207 bytes).

Here is my code to generate the request :

```
// Send the subscription           
$resource = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_POST, count($postFields));
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postString);
$result = curl_exec($resource);
```

Here is the result of the curlinfo debug :

```
17.418212 total_time : Total transaction time in seconds for last transfer
0.064612 namelookup_time : Time in seconds until name resolving was complete
0.437222 connect_time : Time in seconds it took to establish the connection
0.946509 pretransfer_time : Time in seconds from start until just before file transfer begins
17.418172 starttransfer_time : Time in seconds until the first byte is about to be transferred
0 redirect_count : Number of redirects
0 redirect_time : Time in seconds of all redirection steps before final transaction was started
207 size_upload : Total number of bytes uploaded
11 speed_upload : Average upload speed
130 size_download : Total number of bytes downloaded
7 speed_download : Average download speed
```

On curlinfo documentation : http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_getinfo.html, it is said that the size_upload and speed_upload are in bytes and bytes/second respectively.

**10 bytes/s is not very fast, is it?
Where can I find other debug infos, and what can I do to improve this speed?**

Additional info : 
both servers sending and receiving data have good bandwidth
and both are in the same city

Comment: +1 for having debugged a curl call. Most users here with curl problems don't even know about `curl_error()`. Welcome to Stack Overflow! :)

Comment: How fast is the request when you make it in your browser? Could it be that the remote script takes 17 seconds to generate the data?

Comment: It looks like performance problem on server side.

Comment: I'm testing the request in my browser now, not an easy url so let me compute all this :)

Comment: @Pekka웃 Indeed the request is long via browser as well. I am still to verify this on partner's side, but it seems that the remote script is slowing us down. I still need to optimize this, but now I know that cURL is not in cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like performance problem on server side.

Speed reported by curl_getinfo() is calculated like this:

```
bytesPerSecond = totalBytesReceived/totalTime
```

where totalTime is curl_exec execution time.

If server response is delayed (server is busy etc.) You may wait 1 minute for getting 60 bytes in last millisecond and reported speed will be 1 byte per second, it doesnt matter how fast is network connection between servers.

Comment: Ah yes it's obvious with your bytes/s count method, I intuitively saw this upload speed as network connection, but it makes a lot of sense this way. Your answer + Pekka's insight got me on the right track.

Comment: @np1987 So you should try to optimize code on server side somehow. Good luck.